# Windows 10 Keeps Freezing Suddenly

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

My laptop (HP with Samsung SSD) suddenly freezes and I can't do anything except holding the power button to shut down. Testing hardware from bios has shown that all items are working correctly. The problem began 3 days ago, so I was concerned that the last Windows update might be responsible for it, so I updated all drivers with IOBit tools, but it continued to freeze. Is anyone able to help me?

Windows version is 20H2 (OS Build 19042.1081)

Comment: Configure your computer for full crash dumps. Then type `verifier /standard /all` in a administrator command prompt and restart. You should now blue screen rather than hang. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/driver-verifier for details. Does this generate a crash dump?

Comment: "Configure your computer for full crash dumps." Is there a possibility that it can damage my system or data?

Comment: If you can't boot due to a faulty driver then the answer on this page gives you two solutions. A repair install. To diagnose you need a crash dump or connect another computer with a debugger via a port. There are two  ways to get a crash dump on a hang. Either may be prevented from working by the hang. And as crash dumps are retrospective debugging it really annoying if analysing a mini crash dump (the default) to find out you needed the full one.

Comment: Thank you. It happens randomly for no particular reason, and the laptop starts up after shutting it down using the power key. Therefore, the problem isn't a boot issue. This is a problem that I would like to find out the reason for and fix.

Comment: It may become a boot issue if verifier is turned on. It monitors drivers (who are normally not monitored for speed reasons) and will crash at the first incorrect call rather than letting the error propagate and corrupt memory.

Comment: @user1292580 There may be some truth to your statement. However, I have not yet found a solution.

Comment: Did you turn verifier on or not. You need to be specific. Did verifier generate a dump file - yes or no. Has your computer hung since turning verifier on - yes or no.

Comment: @user1292580 I did not try this yet, since I wasn't sure what the consequences would be!

Comment: You need a dump file or a second computer to go further. There are two ways to get a dump file. The aim is to run this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-the--analyze-extension.

Answer (score 0):

> My laptop (HP with Samsung SSD) suddenly freezes and I can't do
> anything except holding the power button to shut down. Testing
> hardware from bios has shown that all items are working correctly.

Two possible solutions to this kind of problem assuming (as you posted No hardware errors, especially the drive).

**(1) Windows 10 Repair Install.**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  Use the option to
> Keep Everything.

**(2) Reinstall Windows.**

If the Repair does not work, back everything up and re-install Windows fresh.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but In my opinion, this isn't the first suggestion that comes to an engineer's mind.

Comment: A Repair Install Keep Everything takes some time, but otherwise leaves everything the same and possibly the error fixed. That is why I suggest it. This is often faster than searching for the specific problems that are occurring.

Comment: You are right, but I think we could learn from these issues again as an engineer :)